# How do I close the gap after using Screw and Boolean modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm new to Blender and currently attempting to create a rope using the Screw modifier. After 'cutting' the rope with a Boolean shape, I am left with gaps that I need to fill seamlessly. The attached picture illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a copy of the object and I think I found the solution.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTG1U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTG1U.png) Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BagPbbMgAsoyKf-9GXTC_W2LY6edVy9i/view?usp=drive_link Video on how to do it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19yPa8YXLkuxIynXafZjNRb-mZiXl6CSl/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hi! I'm unable to access these links. Could you please provide the solution in text form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boolean doesn't seem to work in this case but you could do it another way. Create your circles, enable the *Auto Smooth* and the *Split Edges & Faces* options:

[image]

Then press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, select all the inner vertices and remove them:

[image]

Now give it the *Screw* modifier, apply it, select the top and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to fill and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to clean the topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Comment: Yup, guaranteed to be both faster and generate prettier geometry. The boolean workflow is nice but it has its limits. :)

Comment: @Gorgious Boolean doesn't seem to work fine in this case :(